# update a record without removing the uploaded file in yii

Tags: php, file, file-upload, yii

I need to UPDATE record with out changing or deleting filename(i mean file) , OR reinsert file again so how i can do this?

here is my `actionCreate`, How i can write update?

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Page;
    if (isset($_POST['Page'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Page'];
        $model->filename = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'filename');
        if ($model->save()) {
            if ($model->filename !== null) {
                $dest = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');
                $model->filename->saveAs($dest . '/' . $model->filename->name);

                $model->save();
            }
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
    }
    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

So Please can anyone find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to change or delete filename in edit/update then ignore filename (and upload part) assuming the file is alrready uploaded and you don't wish to change/delete it.

```
 public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $file = $model->filename;
    if (isset($_POST['Page'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Page'];
        $model->filename = $file;
        if ($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
    }
    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: if i make it like that i will lose the file

Comment: Have you tried doing this? If you're losing the filename in DB after this then you can save the filename in a temporary variable after fetching the model, e.g. `$file = $model->filename;` and assign model's filename back to this variable after you bulk assign the attributes to model, e.g. `$model->filename = $file;`

Comment: Yes i tried doing this and losing filename in DB
Can You Please ReWrite Update action Using the way that u suggested 
Sorry for that coz i have deadline and my mind stop 
Thanks man Very Much

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me -

create a `upload` folder outside `protected` directory and also give read/write permission.

**actionCreate function -**

```
public function actionCreate() {

   $model = new Page();

    if(isset($_POST['Page']) && !empty($_POST['Page'])){

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Page'];

        $rand = rand(1, 999);
        $myfile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'filename');
        $fileName = "{$rand}-{$myfile}";  //Generate unique file name

           if(!empty( $fileName)){
               $model->filename   = $fileName;
               $target_dir = realpath( Yii::getPathOfAlias('application') . '/../upload');
               $target_file = $target_dir . '/' . $fileName;

               if(!$myfile->saveAs($target_file)){ 
                  $model->addError('filename', 'File saving error');
               }
            }

        if(!$model->hasErrors() && $model->validate() && $model->save(false)) {
         $this->redirect(array('view', 'id'=>$model->id, 'msg'=>'success'));
       }
    }
}
```

**actionUpdate function -**

```
public function actionUpdate() {

  $model = Page::model()->findbyPK($id);
  $model->scenario = 'update';

  if(isset($_POST['Page']) && !empty($_POST['Page'])){
     $model->attributes = $_POST['Page'];

     if(empty($_POST['Page']['filename'])) { $file_name = $model->filename; } //store existing file name into a variable if your uploading a file on update

     $rand = rand(1, 999);
     $myfile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'filename');
     $fileName = "{$rand}-{$myfile}";  //Generate unique file name

     if($model->validate()) {
       if(!empty($fileName)) {
           $model->filename = $fileName;
           $target_dir  = realpath( Yii::getPathOfAlias( 'application' ) . '/../upload');
           $target_file  = $target_dir . '/' . $fileName;

           if(!$myfile->saveAs($target_file)){ 
               $model->addError('filename', 'File saving error');
            }
        } 
      else {
             $model->filename = $file_name; //allow existing file name 
           }

     if( !$model->hasErrors() && $model->save(false) ) {
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id'=>$model->id, 'msg'=>'update'));
          }
       }
  }
```

In model rules array define this -

```
array('filename', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, bmp, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'insert, update')
```

Comment: i made it mr Rohit and always message Trying to get property of non-object
 so what i can make

Comment: this is my create action
if (isset($_POST['Page'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Page'];
            $model->filename = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'filename');
            if ($model->save()) {
                if ($model->filename !== null) {
                    $dest = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');
                    $model->filename->saveAs($dest . '/' . $model->filename->name);

                    $model->save();
                }

Comment: @OsamaDiab now i have update my code please try again this and also please remember it's an `actionUpdate` code.

Comment: sorry man i know u do ur best but stay same problem i think its from my side , the last try if u wish can u give me both of actions create and update that u used and Thanks again u do ur best

Comment: @OsamaDiab i have update my whole source code once again and also added `actionCreate()`. now try this code i wish this will also work for you.

Comment: Mr Rohit Suthar Thanks very much man u awesome and brilliant  it`s working now Thanks

Comment: @OsamaDiab your welcome.... hope you will select this one as your best & perfect answer.