# how to update a record with file uploaded already?

Tags: file-upload, yii, action

I want to UPDATE record without losing the File that i have uploaded. Below is my `create` action.

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Page;
        if (isset($_POST['Page']))
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Page'];
            $model->filename = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'filename');
            if ($model->save())
            {
                if ($model->filename !== null)
                {
                    $dest = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');
                    $model->filename->saveAs($dest . '/' . $model->filename->name);

                    $model->save();
                }
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
            }
        }
        $this->render('create', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [update a record without removing the uploaded file in yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106546/update-a-record-without-removing-the-uploaded-file-in-yii)

Answer (score 0):

In yii, `update` method is designed to update the values that you are posting from your form. It will not update all Model properties.

For suppose, your `Page` model has 4 model properties, assume all are mandatory.

- title
- description
- keywords
- image

Since you don't want to update image field, you can make it non mandatory field by setting `scenario` for image field in your Page model rules.

```
class Page extends CActiveRecord
{

   /*
   Coding
   */

   public function rules()
   {
        return array(
            array('title, description,keywords', 'required'),
            array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, png'),
            array('image', 'required', 'on' => 'insert'),

            // => You need image field to be entered on Create, not on Update
            .................

   }
}
```

So, Show file input in your form on Create, Hide on Update action so that image field won't submit.

```
 //Your page form

 <?php if($model->isNewRecord):?>
    echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image');
    echo $form->fileField($model, 'image');
    echo $form->error($model, 'image');
 <?php endif;?>
```

Since your are using Yii-2 you can use `skippOnEmpty` validator for the same.